# What should I name this area of my architecture?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, architectural-patterns, layers, spring-mvc

I am developing an architecture for a new MVC system. The legacy system has a layer it calls "facade", but it is not the classic GoF Facade. It is more like a service aggregator. It is used as a convenience layer to call multiple services, aggregate/munge the responses into the response it needs, and then returns that response to the controller.

What should I name this layer? Some possible ideas are:

- facade (yuck...might cause ambiguity)
- aggregate/aggregator
- collector

Any other thoughts? Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Your layer is indeed not a classical GoF since it orchestrates requests in the subsystem and aggregates responses. It is not either a [remote facade](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/remoteFacade.html).

This kind of layer is called [Service layer](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) in [Martin Fowler's view of application architecture](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/), especially if it is meant to encapsulate the domain model.

In the microservice architecture, your component would probably called an [API gateway](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html):

> Some requests are simply proxied/routed to the appropriate service. It
>   handles other requests by fanning out to multiple services.